# Export MySQL data in SQL or XML format similar to PHPMyAdmin

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, xml, phpmyadmin

I want to take regular backup of a website's SQL database and tables and store it in a local folder on my computer using an application created in .NET.

I want to export all data in a SQL or XML format in the same format as created by PHPMyAdmin. I prefer SQL and XML file because it contains SQL commands while CSV file does not contain table creation and other commands and only has the data.

It is very easy to create a web-service that sends all data in an array and then save the data in a csv format in a local folder using C#/VB but I want to take the complete database backup in XML/CSV in the same format as PHPMyAdmin to make sure I can restore complete database using PHPMyAdmin.

The website is in PHP and database is MySQL. The hosting panel is cPanel with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659534/backup-mysql-tables-with-php

Comment: There are two points of your question, one backing up your MSSQL db, and copying your db to MySql. With which one do you need help?